# Run Time Error 1004 'Application Defined or Object Defined Error' - deleting shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete all the shapes within a certain range.

The line that gives me the error is : 
If Not Intersect(Range(sShape.TopLeftCell.Address), myR) Is Nothing Then

Specifically, it says: 
"sShape.TopLeftCell.Address = "
when I hover over the line in vba.

My full code is as follows:

```
Sub Delete_Arrows_DD()
Dim i As Integer
Dim t As Range
Set t = Cells.Find(What:="Trend", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If ActiveSheet.Name = "SCORECARD" Then
    i = 4
        Do While Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
            Call Check_for_Arrow_DD(i, t)
    i = i + 1
    Loop
Else
    i = 2
        Do While Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
            Call Check_for_Arrow_DD(i, t)
    i = i + 1
    Loop
End If
End Sub

Sub Check_for_Arrow_DD(i As Integer, t As Range)
 Dim sShape As Shape
 Dim myR As Range    
 Set myR = Cells(i, t.Column)
    For Each sShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not Intersect(Range(sShape.TopLeftCell.Address), myR) Is Nothing Then
            sShape.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Specifically, it says: "sShape.TopLeftCell.Address =<Application-defined or object-defined error> " when I hover over the line in vba.

Comment: Note that you have set myR to be equal to a single cell, not many cells. Also, perhaps you have shapes which have an undefined space (not sure if this is possible). I've mostly copied your code and thrown in some shapes and ranges, and it works as you've written it.

Comment: Doesn't "Call Check_for_Arrow_DD(i, t)" and "Sub Check_for_Arrow_DD(i As Integer, t As Range)" pass the variables? When I step through the code both I and t pass correctly.  I'm basically trying to cycle through a set of cells (i, t) and see if any of the shapes on the spreadsheet have a cell (I, t) as their top left cell... if that makes any sense

Comment: You're right, scratch that last comment; I didn't see either of the Calls there. Are you sure t always finds a match in the first sub?

Comment: Positive. There is always a column with "Trend" as the header.  Funny thing - when I initially open the spreadsheet with shapes already on it the code works.  If I add shapes and try to run the code again, the error pops up... thoughts?

Comment: That is odd; I tested with shapes inside and outside my defined range, and it didn't cause any errors... is there anything different about the shapes in your workbook already vs the ones you manually insert afterwards?

Comment: What if you did `Set myR = Cells(i, t.Column).Address`?

Comment: That gives me a "Run-time error '424': Object Required", and myR reads as nothing.   If I get rid of the "Set" I get a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Bacon - the shapes are the same. I use a macro to insert them based on what people select, so I'm wondering if something about that isn't jiving?  They're two completely different macros though, so I feel like they shouldn't have any issues...

Comment: Just figured out that if I save the workbook before running the macro it runs fine... any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: what tot do `if t=nothing` ? when it errors, debug,  go to immediate window and `?t`

Comment: On the sheets I'm using there will always be a cell with "Trend" in it, I'm positive of that, so t should never be nothing.